# Q: When can we say that the starting value is near the root in Newton Raphson method?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I would like to know when can I use the Newton Raphson methos to find an approximation of a root. We know that it can be used or that it is possible to work when the starting value is near of the root; but what is near? I mean, if for example if I've got $f(x)=(x-3)^{1/2}$ I know that the root would be $3$, so can I start from the point $p_0=4$? Is $4$ near $3$???

Comment: The exact criterion for nearness is difficult to work out and surprisingly poorly documented in the world of mathematics, but it has to do with the derivative of the function at the root. A function with a steeper slope at the root will converge faster and for a larger interval around the root than a function with a shallow slope at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle it may be possible to determine the immediate basin of attraction of a root $r$ of your function $f$, i.e. the largest interval $(a,b)$ containing $r$ such that Newton's method starting at any point in $(a,b)$ converges to $r$.  Namely, $a$ and $b$ (if finite) are the closest points to left and right of $r$ which are either roots of $f'$, or points where $f$ is not differentiable, or they form a $2$-cycle for Newton's method.

However, in practice the simplest thing to do, to tell whether a point is "sufficiently close", is usually just to try it and see what happens to the iterations.

Your example $f(x) = (x-3)^{1/2}$ is not a good candidate for Newton's method, because (if you stick to real numbers) the function is not defined for $x < 3$ and (even if you allow complex numbers) is not differentiable at $x=3$. If you start at any $x_0 > 3$, the very first iteration will take you to numbers $< 3$.  Perhaps you mean $(x-3)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to characterize a symmetric open interval $I = (r-\delta,r+\delta)$ around the root $r$ such that Newton's method converges to $r$ for all $x_0 \in I$.

Newton's method is a special case of the functional iteration $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$. It corresponds to the choice of $$g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}.$$

Now if $J$ is a *closed* interval and $h : J \rightarrow J$ is a contractive mapping, then $h$ has exactly one fixed point $\xi \in J$ and the functional iteration $x_{n+1} = h(x_n)$ will converge to $\xi$ for all $x_0 \in J$. This is the celebrated *contractive mapping theorem*. The condition that $J$ be closed is necessary. A contractive mapping $h : J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $$\exists L \in [0,1) \: \forall x, y \in J \: : \: |h(x) - h(y)| \leq L |x-y|.$$ If $h$ is differentiable and $|h'(t)| \leq L < 1$ for all $t \in J$, then the mean value theorem of differentiation implies that $h$ is a contractive mapping.

Now in terms of Newton's method we have $$g'(x) = \frac{f(x) f''(x)}{f'(x)}.$$ Clearly, $g'(r) = 0$, because $f(r) = 0$. Now let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval of the form $I = (r-\delta, r+\delta)$ such that $$\forall x \in I \: : \: |g'(x)| < 1.$$
I will now show that Newton's method will converge to $r$ for all $x_0 \in I$. I cannot immediately deploy the contractive mapping theorem, because $I$ is an open interval. However, if $\rho = |r-x_0|$, then $$J = [r-\rho,r+\rho]$$ is a closed interval and $x_0 \in J$ and $J \subset I$. I will now show that $g$ maps $J$ into itself. If $x \in J$, then there exist at least one $t$ between $r$ and $x$ such
$$|g(x) - r| = |g(x)-g(r)| = |g'(t)||x-r|.$$
Since $t \in J \subset I$ we have $|g'(t)| < 1$. It follows that
$$|g(x)-r)| < \rho.$$
This shows that $g$ maps $J$ into itself. By the contractive mapping theorem, we can now conclude that Newton's method converges to $r$. Since $x_0 \in I$ was arbitrary, the proof is complete.

Now for some illustrative examples.

1. The equation $f(x) = x^2 - 2 = 0$ can be used to compute $\sqrt{2}$. We have $$g'(x) = \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{x^2-2}{2x^2}.$$ We have $|g'(x)| < 1$ if and only if $|x^2-2| < 2 |x|$. It follows that $x<-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ or $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} < x$. By the previous analysis we can choose $\delta = \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ and Newton's method will converge to $\sqrt{2}$ for any $x_0 \in I = (\sqrt{2} - \delta, \sqrt{2} + \delta)$. Note: Far more is true for this specific function $f$.
2. The equation $f(x) = (x-3)^2$ was suggested by @RobertIsrael. Then $$g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x - \frac{(x-3)^2}{2(x-3)} = x - \frac{1}{2}(x-3).$$ We find that $g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ and Newton's method converges linearly for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Note: This is readily seen from $$3-g(x) = -\frac{1}{2}(3-x).$$